# Sorting the files using the date from the filenames

Tags: java

I have a bunch of files with names

```
32f245bb02abd408a6f0e997640f7e84d3cdf0e4May 2, 2016.java
a5c3fc386ee6ff7259f4004128baff8a961ec804May 3, 2016.java
eaefc7552ab8ce39ea26272f995476869ed91e1aMay 3, 2016.java
```

I want to arrange them with the dates (in the file names). I use regex to extract the date from the file names and sorted them but now I'm stuck at sorting the files according to date. I try renaming the files but dates are repeating and cant use the creation/modified/access dates as all are the same.

```
File directory2 = new File("path to files");

            String newfile="";
                Set<String> source= new HashSet<String>();  

                ArrayList<String> datestring=new ArrayList<String>();
                try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(directory2.toString()))) {                   
                     paths.skip(1)
                          .forEach(s->{source.add(s.toString());});
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                for(Iterator<String> it=source.iterator(); it.hasNext();) { 
                        newfile = it.next().toString();
                        File f = new File(newfile);
                        String Date = f.getName();

                        String regex2 = "((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))(\\s+)(\\d+)(,)(\\s+)((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])";
                        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
                        Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher(Date);
                        while(m2.find()) {
                            String file= m2.group(0);
                            datestring.add(file);
                        }
              }

              Collections.sort(datestring, new Comparator<String>() {
                        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            try {
                                return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });     

        }
```

I try to rename the files after extracting the date as follows but still if the date is repeating its not possible to rename them and still no luck with sorting them according to the date.

```
for(Iterator<String> it=source.iterator(); it.hasNext();) { 
                    newfile = it.next().toString();
                    File f = new File(newfile);
                    String Date = f.getName();                      
                    for (String datematch:datestring) {
                        if(Date.contains(datematch)) {
                            f.renameTo(new File("path to new directory"+datematch+".java")); 

                        }
                    }


                }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what works with your code and what doesn't and where the problem is. I undestand the problem is that the dates are not unique? Or do you have a problem with compiling your code? 

What would you expect and what do you currently see if you try to compile / run it?

Comment: Im stcuk at how can I now use these dates to save the files and sort them?

Comment: Since the text before the date is of fixed length, why don't you just do a `substring` followed by `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: okay you are proposing a simpler approach but question is again how can I sort he files?

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you stay away from `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: So what do you want to happen with the files that have the same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code in Java 8 to sort your files based on date on the filename.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        try (Stream<Path> filesStream = Files.list(Paths.get("/tmp/stackoverflow-files"))) {
            List<String> files = filesStream.map(Path::getFileName)
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .map(filename -> new Pair<>(filename, filename.substring(40).replace(".java", "")))// The hash seems to be fixed of size 40
                    .map(fileAndDate -> new Pair<>(fileAndDate.getKey(), LocalDate.parse(fileAndDate.getValue(), dateFormatter)))
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getValue))
                    .map(Pair::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
```

What the code does :

- get all files on a path
- get file name
- keep filename and manipulate a copy of it to have a localDate by :

  - removing the hash (of size 40 apparently)
  - removing .java
  - transform to LocalDate
- sort by LocalDate
- return only filenames list after sorting by date
- print list of files

Output :

```
[32f245bb02abd408a6f0e997640f7e84d3cdf0e4May 2, 2016.java, eaefc7552ab8ce39ea26272f995476869ed91e1aMay 3, 2016.java, a5c3fc386ee6ff7259f4004128baff8a961ec804May 3, 2016.java]
```